# Put elements of a triangular matrix in a vector

Tags: python, matrix, vector, triangulation

I am trying to get the upper diagonal elements of correlation matrix mS. So for that I am using np.triu (I don't want to have the ones on the diagonal, so I use k=1). However, I want to have those elements in a vector. I have already read lots of thins about np.triu_indices, but the code doesn't work, because I get the error: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

```
mS= [[1, .8, .6, .8, .7, .8, .6, .9, .5, .6, .8], 
     [.8, 1, .8, .5, .6, .7, .7, .8, .5, .8, .7], 
     [.6, .8, 1, .7, .8, .6, .7, .6, .7, .7, .9], 
     [.8, .5, .7, 1, .8, .6, .8, .7, .6, .9, .8], 
     [.7, .6, .8, .8, 1, .5, .8, .9, .9, .8, .6], 
     [.8, .7, .6, .6, .5, 1, .9, .7, .5, .9, .8], 
     [.6, .7, .7, .8, .8, .9, 1, .6, .8, .7, .7], 
     [.9, .8, .6, .7, .9, .7, .6, 1, .8, .6, .9], 
     [.5, .5, .7, .6, .9, .5, .8, .8, 1, .9, .8], 
     [.6, .8, .7, .9, .8, .9, .7, .6, .9, 1, .8], 
     [.8, .7, .9, .8, .6, .8, .7, .9, .8, .8, 1]]
mS= np.array(mS)

mSi= np.triu(mS, k=1).

# Show mSi
mSi = array([[0. , 0.8, 0.6, 0.8, 0.7, 0.8, 0.6, 0.9, 0.5, 0.6, 0.8],
   [0. , 0. , 0.8, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.7, 0.8, 0.5, 0.8, 0.7],
   [0. , 0. , 0. , 0.7, 0.8, 0.6, 0.7, 0.6, 0.7, 0.7, 0.9],
   [0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0.8, 0.6, 0.8, 0.7, 0.6, 0.9, 0.8],
   [0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0.5, 0.8, 0.9, 0.9, 0.8, 0.6],
   [0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0.9, 0.7, 0.5, 0.9, 0.8],
   [0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0.6, 0.8, 0.7, 0.7],
   [0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0.8, 0.6, 0.9],
   [0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0.9, 0.8],
   [0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0.8],
   [0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ]])

 vPR= np.triu_indices(mS, -55)
 This gives me the error
```

I would like to have one array (named vPR) where all the triu elements from above are placed into. Hope someone can help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could generate the index arrays for the diagonal you want

```
r, c = mSi.shape

mSi[np.arange(0, r-1), np.arange(1, c)]

Out[28]: array([0.8, 0.8, 0.7, 0.8, 0.5, 0.9, 0.6, 0.8, 0.9, 0.8])
```

Answer (score 1):

Function `np.triu_indices` gives you a list of indexes of all items above the diagonal. Start with your triangular matrix, trim the left column and bottom row (since they contain all zeros), and extract all other items by indexing:

```
np.triu(mS, k=1)[:-1, 1:][np.triu_indices(mS.shape[0] - 1)]
#array([ 0.8,  0.6,  0.8,  0.7,  0.8,  0.6,  0.9,  0.5,  0.6,  0.8,  0.8,
#        0.5,  0.6,  0.7,  0.7,  0.8,  0.5,  0.8,  0.7,  0.7,  0.8,  0.6...
```